# Is the "baseball choke" legal in Judo?

Tags: judo, sport, chokes, gi

Since at least [1999](https://web.archive.org/web/20010503002314/http://www.ijf.org/rules/html/refree-eng/center.htm#ARTICLE%2027%20-%20Prohibited%20acts%20and%20penalties) judo has banned any chokes applied using the skirt of the jacket. This rule was re-emphasised  in [2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20160427055015/http://www.intjudo.eu/upload/2014_11/22/141664994165105156/ref_rules.pdf) after a variant of *suso-jime* was used to success multiple times by [Yarden Gerbi](https://www.patreon.com/posts/evolution-of-22292882), and it is indeed this style of choke that is used in the example images in the current ruleset.<sup>1</sup>

**Is the baseball choke legal in judo?** It does 'use' the skirt of the gi, in that tori grips it with both hands, but the actual pressure applied to the neck for the choke is done purely with the forearms as in *sode-guruma-jime*.

[image]

---

**Notes:**

1. > <sup>To apply shime-waza using either your own or your opponent’s belt or bottom of the jacket or using only the fingers.</sup>
   >   [image]
   >   <sup>- [IJF SOR 2019](https://78884ca60822a34fb0e6-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/up/2019/10/IJF_Sport_and_Organisation_Rul-1571921763.pdf)</sup>
2. <sup>[Example of choke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9isJu.jpg) in Katsuhiko Kashiwazaki's  [*Fighting Judo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Fighting_Judo.html?id=iD6nAAAACAAJ) (1985) under the name *suso-jime* (裾絞 "apron choke")</sup>
3. <sup>Note the term *suso-jime* seems to be an umbrella term describing [a number of different chokes](https://www.google.com/search?q=suso+jime) involving grabbing the bottom of the gi, including the "Gerbi choke" and variants of *okuri-eri-jime* with a low grip.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Legal

My personal understanding (sorry, no official guidance) is this use of the skirt portion of the jacket is legal. This is basically the same use of the opponent's gi as in *kata juji jime*.

The rules are imprecisely written, which is very annoying. "Using only the fingers" would also seem to preclude *ryote jime*, but *ryote jime* is legal.

Using a belt or the bottom of the jacket as a **garrote** is illegal. This is how the gi was employed in the Gerbi Peruvian necktie variation.